# KDE login screen of wrong monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, sddm

I have Kubuntu 20.04 LTS version. I have two monitors connected to my PC - primary one via HDMI and secondary via DisplayPort. Both have the same resolution.
When I get the KDE login screen (sddm i guess) i see it on both screens, but when I start typing password I can only see the response  on the 'secondary' monitor (not the primary one). How can I set correct behaviour of the login screen on the primary monitor?
When I disconnect secondary monitor, it all works on the primary.
After login I have the 'task panel' and the 'application launcher' on the correct monitor.

Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure this out ?

Comment: I am having the same issue